# How to switch between different database users with different permissions, directly inside my application on Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh

So I'm using Java and MySQL, I created a database with different roles (user/manager/admin etc....) By default, I'm connected as a simple user, but how can I switch my user to the super admin after he authenticates?
Because right now, my connection with MySQL is made in a private constructor with private methods, so at first I thought about putting setters, but I can't access them given that I can't instantiate an object from my class with the private constructor.

ConnexionMySQL.java:

```
    private ResourceBundle bundle = 
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("domaine.properties.config");
    private String url = bundle.getString("sgbd.url");
    private String driver = bundle.getString("sgbd.driver");
    private String mysqlUser = bundle.getString("sgbd.login");
    private String mysqlPassword = bundle.getString("sgbd.password");

private ConnexionMysql(){
        try {
            session = doSshTunnel(this.sshUser, this.sshPassword, this.sshHost, this.sshPort, this.url, this.sshLocalPort,this.sshRemotePort);
            System.out.println("Opened SSH on " + sshHost);
            Class.forName(driver);
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, mysqlUser ,mysqlPassword);
            System.out.println("connect� Mysql");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
      }

public static Connection getInstance(){

        if(instance == null){
        instance = new ConnexionMysql();
          System.out.println("INSTANCIATION DE LA CONNEXION SQL ! ");
        }
        else{
          System.out.println("CONNEXION SQL EXISTANTE ! ");
        }
        return connect;
      }

    public static void disconnect(){
        try {
            connect.close();
            session.disconnect();

            instance = null;
                System.out.println("Deconnexion r�ussie");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

      }
```

I have another config.properties file in which I specified the login and password.
But what if now I wanna change those values in a controller for example after a user authenticates ?

Comment: There is only one method for to change MySQL account applied - reconnection with new account name.

Comment: *I created a database with different roles (user/manager/admin etc....)* Do you mean MySQL roles or the roles created and managed at the application level?

Comment: No I mean MySQL roles with the CREATE NEW ROLE command on MySQL

Comment: But so if I need to reconnect with a new account name, once again, how can I change the username and password with the new logs I want? Because with the code I have above, my logs are stocked in variables, but I can't access them anywhere outside of the class, so what if I wanted to change them from another class' controller  ?

Comment: So this is my case: by default, I have a default user with only a SELECT permission on 3 of my database's tables, but once I log in as an admin for example, I would now have way more roles than just a SELECT on 3 tables, but I'm logging in from another class/controller, so how could I change my variables in my ConnexionMySQL class so now it corresponds to the admin logs ?

Comment: It seems that you must create two classes. First one is used for authentication, it connects to MySQl and checks the account name. If authentication is successful then you create another connection with new account using second object, copy needed values from 1st object to 2nd, then close 1st connection and destroy 1st object. But I do not use Java so I may be wrong...

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as you currently have it, in your ConnexionMysql class, you simply update the values of `mysqlUser` and `mysqlPassword` and connect again. You could do this by adding a new constructor that accepts the username and password as an input in the ConnexionMysql class, and just create a new instance for a new user.

Comment: @sorifiend The problem is that I created my Connection class as a singleton pattern, so I can't create another public constructor that accepts 2 parameters, because then I could have 2 instances of my connection class

Comment: Then you'll need to break the pattern or create a new unrelated class with basically duplicate code, or you'll need to build a wrapper around and maybe use a boolean toggle value that will let the single instance of the class swap between users. Or use any one of the many other ways that this could be achieved, you don't need to complicate the issue, simply log out of the first user, and log back in with the next in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the easiest way to solve this problems will be to make as many clases as roles you want to create (of course if you want to leave your constructor private).

In my opinion it should look something like this:

1. ConnexionMySQLuser;
2. ConnexionMySQLmanager;
3. ConnexionMySQLadmin;

Of course if you have numerous of roles it can create problems in future.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it this way then see how it goes